# What does the German AZF radio license test comprise of in the oral examination?

Tags: radio-communications, germany

I understand you're required to have an AZF-license, on top of a BZF-license to do IFR radio transmissions in Germany; I also figure the test is similar to the BZF license with a written and an oral part.

What's a typical sequence of radio calls in the oral test? Are there any particular gotchas one should be aware of?

I've read through a list of phrases (out of something called NfL), so I'm vaguely familiar with the differences from US phraseology, but I got from the BZF test there are other differences, like you tend to get a question "Are you ready to copy", rather than the "advise ready to copy" I'm used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of differences in the US and European communication.

I got my AZF about a year ago and basically you have to do simulated IFR departure and approach. In addition you will have to fill out an IFR flightplan and answer 30 IFR communication questions.

I would say it is a similar difficulty like the BZF, it might be even a little bit easier, as you just have to repeat what the controller tells you (but you still have to be aware where you are).

An example on how radio communication is done can be found at http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP413Supplement.pdf or http://training.ivao.de/trainingsunterlagen.html?tx_drwiki_pi1%5Bkeyword%5D=IFR-Funkbeispiel

I would however recommend a training at a flight school (which costs around 150 Euros).

Answer (score 0):

Training at a flight school is absolutely recommended. It is true that the AZF is a lot easier then the BZF exam, but you should be aware of what's coming up and that's not done by reading but by practice.

If the controller is in a good mood on your exam day you may have spent a little to much money on preparation, but if they had no breakfast that morning you are happy to be used for copying clearances you will never hear when you are sitting in a plane and no longer at a table.